# Android - BiometricPrompt detect whether is a face id or touch id

Tags: android, biometrics, touch-id, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

In my Android app, I use this code to ask user for biometrical authentication:

```
val title = "..."
val subtitle = "..."

BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setSubtitle(subtitle)
            .build()
```

My case is, that I want to customise the `title` and `subtitle` in case of **touchID** usage or **faceID**.

Is there any way to detect which biometrical method is going to be shown to the user?

I found out that we can check if a feature is available or not with:

```
val hasFaceId = context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE)
```

But `FEATURE_FACE` is only available on Android API 29, and I need something that works even for older Android versions.

Comment: Any luck in solving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per latest Android Biometric docs, there are no such APIS which can solve your requirement.

Comment: could you add the ref. link